# Как вернуть сериализованый в PHP массив обратно в строку на C#

Tags: php, c#

В базе данных есть вот такое вот нечто вида:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:1:"5";}
```

В интернете нарыл, что это нечто получается в PHP из JSON'а.

Вопрос: Как это нечто, преобразовать обратно в нормальный JSON с помощью **C#**.

Comment: `$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';` `var_dump(json_decode($json, true));` результат `array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}` вот это Json из PHP, а то что вы привели какой-то бред .

Comment: убрал излишнее форматирование см: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вы привели в вашем вопросе, никаким образом не связанно с `json`! У вас в  вопросе сериализованный массив `PHP`. Для его сериализации и десериализации необходимо использовать функции [serialize](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php) и [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unserialize.php) соответственно.

Уж если хотите делать это дело на [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) то:

1. [Sharp Serialization Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/csphpserial/)
2. [PHP Serializer/Deserialize](https://gist.github.com/xiangwan/1225981#file-c-php-serializer-cs)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/213987) Последние два предложения совершенно лишние, не хотите поменять формулировки, а то и вовсе убрать? Ихму, лишь кичиться своим превосходством в поле ответа.

Comment: На json не похоже потомучто сериализованн.

Comment: @ViniPux так JSON сам по себе **формат** сериализации (а не данные, которые в нём представлены: массивы, мапы, строки, числа, нуллы). Приведенная вами строка не является корректным JSON, значит это не JSON, а какой-то другой формат. Всё.

Comment: Да это уже понятно. Заказчик 'признался', что это сериализованые php массивы